# How do I download a stock price in Excel 2013? Is there an equivalent to Google Doc's GoogleFinance spreadsheet function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

In a Google Docs spreadsheet, I can use this cell formula:

```
=GoogleFinance("GOOG", "price")
```

to download the latest price of a stock. Is there an equivalent function in Excel 2013?

Earlier versions of Excel had a [smart tag feature](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/get-a-stock-quote-HP010216958.aspx) that downloaded a ton of data for each ticker (too much, in fact, if you just need the price), and I've seen sources that suggest the [Bing Finance app](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/bing-finance-beta-WA103795935.aspx?queryid=cea11096-c1d1-41b1-ac5b-0028f07493ba&css=finance%20bing) for Excel 2013. Unfortunately this has been discontinued.

Is there a simple way to do this? I literally just need the most recent price, and I don't care if it's delayed, comes from Yahoo Finance, etc. Presumably I could write VBA code to download a CSV file from YF, parse it and so on, but I'm hoping to avoid creating a macro-enabled workbook.

Comment: This is not a feature that Excel supports out of the box

Comment: In excel 2007/2010 `data - existing connection - MSN MoneyCentral Investory Stock Quotes` works, was this removed for 2013? **edit** - yeah it looks like it was removed and Bing Finance App is the "replacement". You could set up a `data - from web` query to msn money, but that would be tedious.

Comment: @Raystafarian How would I set up a new data query?

Comment: It seems you may need to use [power query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-query-101-HA103993784.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104019755) in 2013 [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-data-from-external-data-sources-HA104003952.aspx#_Toc381890193)

Comment: There are four Stock apps in the [Office Store](https://store.office.com/search.aspx?productgroup=Excel&category=Financial%2BManagement&qu=stock). Are they useful?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not the OP, but I think the most valuable answer would be something that uses existing functionality in Excel 2013 and/or is free.

Comment: @Excellll: I think the only two solutions here are either VBA or an app, thus creating new functionality. Wouldn't it be worthwhile to at least check the two free apps?

Comment: @harrymc Post them. I only placed the bounty because this seemed a worthwhile question that had received no useful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a UDF like this -

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetTickerPrice(ByVal ticker As String) As Double

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim pageData As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/fi-126.1." & ticker & ".NAS?symbol=" & ticker & "=PRFIMQ"

    IE.Navigate URL

     Do Until IE.ReadyState >= 4
            DoEvents
     Loop

     Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

     Set pageData = IE.document

     GetTickerPrice = pageData.getElementsByClassName("precurrentvalue")(0).innertext

     Set IE = Nothing
     Set pageData = Nothing
End Function
```

Now you can use `GetTickerPrice("GOOG")` and get the current price.

---

I did take this over to [Codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121685/excel-retrieving-data-from-website-through-it) for some input.

Comment: Would it not be best to format as Double instead of Long, so you don't lose the decimal information? Then the end user can decide if they want to round it.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But it's *really* slow -- about 20 seconds to get one stock price. I'm assuming opening IE and loading the URL there are the bottlenecks. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: @Jonno yes, I see Excellll made the change

Comment: @Excellll I'll try to see if there's a way around it, maybe forcing IE to be silent, but unless we can find a database like there used to be, we might be stuck (at least for older versions of excel).

Comment: @Excellll there's a pretty decent [response at CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/121693/75587) to my approach. It seems like it's different enough that it wouldn't be considered the same as my answer.

Comment: I see that the main suggestion is that this process be used as a macro, not as a UDF, which I agree with. The UDF was the desirable feature though (like the GoogleFinance function on Google Sheets). +1 for effort and providing something that works, even if it's not ideal.

Comment: @Excellll I think if the class example is implemented, a UDF can still be used, just calling the macro. Which should work as long as it's not editing itself, I think.

Comment: +1 for your efforts. However to quote from the OP `Presumably I could write VBA code to download a CSV file from YF, parse it and so on, but I'm hoping to avoid creating a macro-enabled workbook`. And I saw your http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121685/excel-retrieving-data-from-website-through-internet-explorer/121693#121693] - excellent work

Answer (score 3):

There are four Stock apps in the [Office Store](https://store.office.com/search.aspx?productgroup=Excel&category=Financial%2BManagement&qu=stock) at the moment.
Two of them are free :

[**Stock Connector**](https://store.office.com/stock-connector-WA104379220.aspx?assetid=WA104379220&sourcecorrid=abae3e54-2b68-41a8-bdc1-3c8003928e3b&searchapppos=1)

[image: Stock Connector]

[**Stock Tile**](https://store.office.com/stock-tile-WA104356783.aspx?assetid=WA104356783&sourcecorrid=abae3e54-2b68-41a8-bdc1-3c8003928e3b&searchapppos=0)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is an Add-In called [Stock Quote Add-In For Excel 2013](https://pmstockquote.codeplex.com/) which does this, and has a version for 2013. Personally I could not get it to work, but it has been around for a few years so it was probably just me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This does help answer the question but could you possibly add info about how this plugin should be used?